# Custom css style in wordpress but not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I've struggled with this problem with a while and still couldn't find the solution. I've created custom CSS for the google calendar in wordpress page, but the thing is, it is not working.

I put this code in the page and I put in custom css of the theme as well, but it not showing up:

```
<style>
span#calendarTitle {display:none !important;}
.header img {display:none !important;}
.tab-name {display:none !important;}
.footer {display:none !important;}
.ui-rtsr-first-tab {display:none !important;}
</style>
```

Was hoping if someone could see what I am doing wrong. Attached the live page link: http://dilog.com.my/testing-page/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot change the style of a page, displayed in an iframe unless you have direct access to the source html and/or css files. for your reference please read this for details [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Try adding bit of jQuery function to hide content within the iframe

```
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  span#calendarTitle { display:none; }  </style>"));
});
```

Comment: Thank for your help. Where should I add this jQuery? @Shirish Dhotre

Comment: when I first see this I though impossible ... I really like your answer it solve alot of problems ... but today I am out of upvotes .

Comment: Hi, @ShirishDhotre I still fail to change it, can you guide me where should I put the script?